# Convert a List to integer without using map() or join()

Tags: python, list, int

if  I have

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

How can i make it

```
list=123456
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you consider a *library function* ?

Comment: like map() or join()

Comment: `map` is a builtin function and `join` is a `str.method`... by that definition you can't use anything... you must have an idea of what you're expected to use to do this task?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
inlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
length = len(inlist)
s = 0
for i in range(length):
    s += (inlist[i] * ( 10 ** (length-1-i)))
inlist = s
print(inlist)
```

This will give you:

```
123456
```

You need to utilize the power of `10` to multiply it with each number.

Note that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it is a Python keyword.

Another version (without using any built-in functions at all):

```
inlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
count = 1
s = 0
for elem in inlist[::-1]:
    s += (elem * ( 10 ** (count-1)))
    count += 1
inlist = s
print(inlist)
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldn`t use map or join :(

Comment: @YigitPektasoglu I will edit my answer then, thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @YigitPektasoglu then you should include that in your question... what else can't you use - what are you expected to use?

Comment: Depends if you're allowed `len` or `range` now :)

Comment: I can use them but not map or join and sorry for not to be clear

Comment: @YigitPektasoglu edited answer without `map` or `join`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VasilisG. and sorry for you guys to make it hard to explain

Comment: @YigitPektasoglu you're welcome, don't think about it, just a few clarifications to point us in a direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by `for` and `join` likes the following:

```
int(''.join([str(i) for i in my_list]))
```